# pdfbox merge pdf with form

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a simple pdf file (a.pdf) and a pdf file with some forms in it (checkboxes, textfields, ...). I want to merge them:

```
    public void merge () throws IOException, COSVisitorException, CryptographyException, InvalidPasswordException {
    PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
    PDDocument arg0 = PDDocument.load("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\a.pdf");
    PDDocument arg1 = PDDocument.load("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\b.pdf");
    if (arg1.isEncrypted()) {
        arg1.decrypt("consol");
        arg1.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
    }

    merger.appendDocument(arg0, arg1);
    arg0.save("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\xout.pdf");
    arg0.close();
    arg1.close();
}
```

This basically works however the forms are not included in the target pdf file anymore. Do you have any hints for me?

Answer (score 0):

try this out  :

```
try { 
        PDFMergerUtility mpdf = new PDFMergerUtility();
        String folder = "C:/Users/.../Desktop"; 
        String destinationFileName = "output.pdf"; //say
        File folderFile = new File(folder); 
        if (folderFile.isDirectory()) { 
              mpdf.addSource(folder + "/" + "a.pdf");
              mpdf.addSource(folder+ "/"+"b.pdf"); 
              mpdf.setDestinationFileName(folder + "/"+ destinationFileName);
              mpdf.mergeDocuments();
       } catch(Exception ex) {
           logger.error(ex);
       }
```

Hope, this will help....

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but the text fields are not editable anymore with this...